# gm3u app needs libgnomeui.so.32 - how do I install it?

Tags: music, shared-library

I have an music app that reports the following when I run it

`gm3u: error while loading shared libraries: libgnomeui.so.32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I can't seem to find what package will install this library.

Comment: Look at this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474778

Comment: That solution - sudo apt-get install libgnomeui32 - no longer works as the package is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a very old package -- `libgnomeui.so.32` refers to the old GNOME 1 libraries. It's no longer available in Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, I tried compiling the *gm3u* source code but even that wants the GNOME1 development libraries and fails...

Comment: Is there no backward compatibility for gnome apps?

Comment: If you can recompile from source, yes, but in this case the source is poorly written... Unfortunately, it's like trying to run a Windows 3.1 application on Windows 7...